# Should we mock built-in functions in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Should we mock built-in functions in Jest? Below is the code:

```
if (!req?.headers?.authorization?.startsWith("Bearer")) {
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ error: "Missing Authorization header with Bearer token" });
}
```

Should I mock this `startsWith` function?

I am using this mock request:

```
const mockRequest = () => {
  return {
    headers: {
      authorization: {
        startsWith: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: No you shouldn't. Whatever you're sending in in your test (e.g., the request, with some authorization headers) you should put a correct-ish header.

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using this mockRequest, const mockRequest = () => {
  return {
    headers: {
      authorization: {
        startsWith: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
      },
    },
  };
};

Comment: Instead, do something like `const mockRequest = () => { return { headers: { authorization: 'Bearer my-header' }, }, }; };`. You can also test the opposite case when the header is not present/correct.

Comment: You shouldn't be testing controllers this way at all. You don't own the request interface.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, Can you please explain how should I do this?